# Does $U(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$ represent transitive, monotonic preferences?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

That this utility function represents monotonic preferences, I think it's clear. Both goods have positive and constant marginal utilities. What I think is less clear is if this preference relation is transitive. How can I assess it?

Comment: How about applying the definitions of "utility function represents preferences" and of "transitive preferences"?

Comment: A preference relation is transitive if $A \succ B, B \succ C \implies A \succ C$. So if there's $p,q, r \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U(p) > U(q), U(q) > U(r) \implies U(p) > U(r)$ then $U()$ represents a transitive preference relation. Hmm... Yeah, positive and constant derivatives should do the trick to guarantee it. Thanks, man.

Comment: $U(x,y) = (x+y)^2$ is a monotonic transformation of $U^{'}(x,y) = x+y$.(the transformation is $f(z) = z^2$)

Comment: @PedroCavalcanteOliveira Why do you need anything about derivaties? Why is
$$
U(A) > U(B) \text{ and } U(B) > U(C) \Rightarrow U(A) > U(C)
$$
not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transitivity.**

*Definition.* If $A \succsim B$ and $B \succsim C$, then $A \succsim C$.

*Proof.* Suppose $A \succsim B$ and $B \succsim C$. Then by definition of a utility representation, $U(A) \geq U(B)$ and $U(B) \geq U(C)$. By the transitivity of $\geq$, we have $U(A) \geq U(C)$. And so again by definition of a utility representation, $A \succsim C$, so that $\succsim$ is transitive.

**Monotonicity.**

*Definition.* If $x_1\geq x_2$ and $y_1\geq y_2$, then $\left(x_1,y_1\right)\succsim\left(x_2,y_2\right)$.

*Proof.* Suppose $x_1\geq x_2 \left(\geq 0\right)$ and $y_1\geq y_2\left(\geq 0\right)$. Then $$U\left(x_1,y_1\right) = x_1^2 +y_1^2 +2x_1y_1 \geq x_2^2 +y_2^2 +2x_2y_2 = U\left(x_2,y_2\right),$$ so that definition of a utility representation, $\succsim$ is monotonic.

Answer (score 1):

Any preference relation represented by an utility function is transtive.

Suppose $x \succsim y$ and  $y \succsim z$ and $\succsim$ is represented by $U$. Then $U(x) \geq U(y)  $ and $U(y) \geq U(z)$, so $U(x) \geq U(z)$  and then $x \succsim z$.

Comment: This is just a consequence of the transitivity in the real numbers to which the utility function maps, right?